# Android Scrollview content size smaller when should be

Tags: android

I want to have a "fixed_space" at the top of screen and a "scrollview" at the bottom of the screen which should be below fixed_space. The rest of the screen is a container "rest_space".

Unfortunately my scrollview has a shorter height(by 100dp which fixed_space has) ,if content is too big/scrollable.

I tried to achieve same with ConstraintLayout and RelativeLayout, but I have got same result.
Any ideas why scrollview has 100dp shorter height, as it should be?

EDIT: Scrollview should take as much space as she needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fixed_space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/rest_space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="START OF SCROLLVIEW \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nMIDDLE OF SCROLLVIEW \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nEND OF SCROLLVIEW" />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the "rest_space" view?that should be the problem

Comment: Tell me ratio of fixed_space, rest_space and scrollview you want.

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley ScrollView should only take so much space she needs.  If I delete rest_space, scrollview will take whole space between fixed_space and bottom screen.

Comment: @R.R.M. where is no ratio. Scrollview should take as much space as she needs.

Comment: Ok. I have posted an answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:id="@+id/fixed_space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/rest_space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scrollview"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="START OF SCROLLVIEW \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nMIDDLE OF SCROLLVIEW \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nEND OF SCROLLVIEW" />

    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I set text to android:text="Start of ScrollView" where is no rest_space and scrollview is not at the bottom of screen as she should be.

Comment: It works! 
Please add closing tag for LinearLayout at the end.

Comment: I have added it. If it worked. Please mark it as correct so that others can find solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this should solve your probem:

First, I started by using RelativeLayout. I did it in order to get the fixed_space aligned to the top and the scrollview aligned to the bottom.

Then I changed the View for a LinearLayout and put a TextView within it so I could use wrap_content and this is the tricky part:

When you use ScrollView with wrap_content and a View with the weight stuff, Android can't make the calculations it needs to get the screen drawed because there is no reference. When I put the TextView with wrap_content itself that gives the reference because Android know the size of the text.

You don't have to use the TextView but you will need anything that gives Android that reference.

In this case, the scrollview is going to be stretched, not the LinearLayout. If you want the second to get strached, then I'm afraid you are going to need to set a fixed height to your scrollview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:id="@+id/fixed_space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rest_space"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fixed_space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <TextView
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_below="@id/rest_space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="START OF SCROLLVIEW \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nMIDDLE OF SCROLLVIEW \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nEND OF SCROLLVIEW" />

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I probably poorly described my question. ScrollView should have a dynamic height. So if TextView inside Scrollview has only "Start of the Scrollview", scrollview height will be only one line height, and will stay at the bottom of the screen. "rest_space" height will take the remaining space between "fixed_space" and "scrollview".